# C - OpenSSL (d2i_RSA_PUBKEY, d2i_RSAPrivateKey e d2i_RSAPublicKey)

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

Criei uma chave privada RSA através do seguinte comando:

```
 openssl genrsa -out keypair.pem 2048
```

Preciso que essas chaves seja, armazenadas em formato DER (PKCS#1). Assim, converti esta chave privada, que está em formato PEM, em dois arquivos em formato DER: um para a chave privada, outro para a chave pública:

```
openssl rsa -inform PEM -in keypair.pem -outform DER -pubout -out public.der

openssl rsa -inform PEM -in keypair.pem -outform DER -out private.der
```

No meu código, eu carreguei os conteúdos de public.der e private.der em duas variáveis char*.

Nenhuma das chamadas abaixo funciona:

```
d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
```

Sei que as chamadas não funcionam pois o retorno de todas ela é `null`.

Também tentei o seguinte:

```
RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);

RSA * rsa = RSA_new();
d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&rsa, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
```

O mesmo resultado, todos retornam `null`.

Meu código de testes é o seguinte:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <openssl/rsa.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>

typedef struct
{
    int len;
    char * bytes;
} FileData;

static FileData readFileBytes(const char * name, int zero_ended)
{
    FILE * fl = fopen(name, "r");
    if (fl == NULL) return (FileData) { .len = 0, .bytes = NULL };
    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_END);
    long len = ftell(fl);
    char * ret = malloc(len + (zero_ended ? 1 : 0));
    fseek(fl, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(ret, 1, len, fl);
    if (zero_ended) ret[len] = 0;
    fclose(fl);
    return (FileData) { .len = len, .bytes = ret };
}

int main()
{
    FileData private_key = readFileBytes("../private.der", 0);
    FileData public_key = readFileBytes("../public.der", 0);

    char* public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    int public_key_length = public_key.len;

    char* private_key_bytes = private_key.bytes;
    int private_key_length = private_key.len;

    RSA * rsa;

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPublicKey(NULL, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    private_key_bytes = private_key.bytes;
    private_key_length = private_key.len;
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPrivateKey(NULL, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSA_PUBKEY(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    public_key_bytes = public_key.bytes;
    public_key_length = public_key.len;
    rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPublicKey(&rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    private_key_bytes = private_key.bytes;
    private_key_length = private_key.len;
    rsa = RSA_new();
    rsa = d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&rsa, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length);
    printf("d2i_RSAPrivateKey(&rsa, &private_key_bytes, private_key_length) != NULL -> %s\n", (rsa != NULL) ? "true" : "false");

    getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No StackOverflow em inglês, obtive a resposta (https://stackoverflow.com/a/36805530/6242158).

Eu estava rodando esse código em Windows, e para que o Windows trate arquivos binários corretamente, basta usar a flag "rb".

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro parâmetro da d2i_RSAPublicKey não pode ser null, tem que ser um ponteiro de RSA.

```
RSA *rsa = RSA_new() ;
d2i_RSAPublicKey(rsa, &public_key_bytes, public_key_length);
```

https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/crypto/i2d_RSA_PUBKEY.html

Comment: O mesmo problema. As três chamadas continuam retornando null. Aparentemente o  formato das chaves não está correto...

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta. incluindo mais detalhes.